# C++ Reading from various text files in the same function

Tags: c++, file, input

I have a program that's supposed to read information about an item from file. The thing is, I have items spread around in different files called "G***.DTA" (where *** = a unique number for a category of items, i.e. "G34.DTA").

To read from these files, I've created a function that uses a for-loop to browse through all category numbers. The for-loop's iteration variable is used to create the filename of the ifstream object I create (1st round G1.DTA, 2nd round G2.DTA etc.). Also, not every category has a file, so there will be some files "missing". So my program can have just G2.DTA, G5.DTA, G10.DTA etc. All the others should be skipped.

Anyway, my program just hangs when I try to read from the file. Can anyone see where my mistake is, if I include the read from file-function, the constructor and the file format?

This function should read from the files:

```
void Items::readItemsFromFile() {
    for(int i = 1; i <= categoryBase->lastCategoryInUse; i++) {
        char filename[STRLEN];
        char buffer[10];
        int nr;
        itoa(i, buffer, 10);                                            // Makes category number a char for strcat()
        strcpy(filename, "G");                                          // Makes "G" first part of filename
        strcat(filename, buffer);                                       // Makes category number (i) second part of filename
        strcat(filename, ".DTA");                                       // Makes ".DTA" suffix of filename
        ifstream infile(filename);

        if(infile) {
            infile >> nr;
            while(!infile.eof()) {
                itemList->add(new Item(nr, infile));
                infile >> nr;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Here's the constructor (int n is sent to a parent class NumElement and set as the item number):

```
Item::Item(int n, ifstream & in): NumElement(n) {
    char buffer[STRLEN];

    in.getline(buffer, STRLEN);
    salesman = new char[strlen(buffer) + 1];  strcpy(salesman, buffer);
    in.getline(buffer, STRLEN);
    title = new char[strlen(buffer) + 1];  strcpy(title, buffer);
    in.getline(buffer, STRLEN);
    description = new char[strlen(buffer) + 1];  strcpy(description, buffer);
    in >> startTime >> endTime >> startPrice >> shipping >> increaseBid >> lastBid >> bidTime; in.ignore();
    }
```

And here's how the file format looks:

```
1
van gogh
summer
beautiful painting
1 2 100 33 5 0 0
3
da vinci
mona lisa
classic
2 3 50 20 3 0 0
```

Comment: `std::string` would make that so much less ugly and error-prone.

Comment: You're writing C++. Why not simply use std::string? Also, you're making the often-repeated mistake of declaring your char buffer to be the exact number bytes you think are OK. Now, if that string is more than STRLEN characters, including the NULL, you have a memory overwrite error.  All of this could be moot point if std::ostringstream and std::string were used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading an integer with `infile >> nr;` the reading stops at a **new line character**(according to your file structure) so before starting to read lines from the file using `getline()` you should call `ifstream::ignore()`. Otherwise `ifstream::getline()` will not read any character which results the stream to be set to a **fail** state and any further reading operation will not be successful(and hence you will not reach the end of file resulting in infinite loop iteration).

```
Item::Item(int n, ifstream & in): NumElement(n) 
{
    char buffer[STRLEN];

    in.ignore(INT_MAX,'\n');//this should be here(ignores every thing up to and including the next newline character)

    in.getline(buffer, STRLEN);
    salesman = new char[strlen(buffer) + 1];  strcpy(salesman, buffer);
    ....
}
```

BTW you should be using std::string. Also see the comment section of your question for additional notes that will help you improve your code.

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem! But for some reason, the program only reads the first entry, and then gives an error. Any clue?

About the use of c-strings: I'm trying to get basic knowledge of how c-strings/char arrays work, before going on to strings. But thanks for the tip!

Comment: What do you mean by the first entry? And what error does it give?

Comment: Sorry, it's actually the LAST entry. By entry, I mean entry in the Item list. When I run my program, it reads from the files, and is supposed to display the entire list of entries (items), but only the last one is displayed, and then an error message saying "An unhandled win32 exception occured in Auction.exe [8944]".

Comment: That may have something to do the way you implement **itemList** Class( assuming its a class).

Answer (score 0):

Any chance your call to std::ifstream::ignore (which defaults to ignoring eof) makes your stream ignore the eof on the last execution of the Item constructor (the last item read from the file)?